# always try-catch external resource calls?

Tags: c#, exception, external

Should I always wrap external resource calls in a try-catch?  (ie. calls to a database or file system)  Is there a best practice for error handling when calling external resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Catch **only exceptions** that you **can handle**. So for example when using external resources, the best practice is to catch **specific** exceptions that you know you can handle. In case of files this can be (IOException, SecurityException, etc), in case of Database the exception can be SqlException or others.

In any case, **don't catch** exceptions that you **don't handle**, let them flow to a upper layer that can. Or if for some reason you do catch exceptions but don't handle them, rethrow them using just *throw;* (which will create an rethrow IL op, as opposed to trow).

In case of using resources that you don't know what type of exceptions might throw, you are kind of forced to catch the general exception type. And in this case the safes thing would be to use the said resources from a different app domain (if possible), or let the exception bubble up to top level (ex UI) where they can be displayed or logged.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are three reasons to have a catch block:

- You can handle the exception and recover (from "low level" code)
- You want to rewrap the exception (again, from "low level" code)
- You're at the top of the stack, and while you can't recover the operation itself, you don't want the whole app to go down

If you stick to these, you should have very few catch blocks compared with `try/finally` blocks - and those `try/finally` blocks are almost always just calling `Dispose`, and therefore best written as `using` statements.

Bottom line: It's very important to have a `finally` block to free resources, but `catch` blocks should usually be rarer.

Answer (score 2):

[> Know when to set up a try/catch block. For example, you can programmatically check for a condition that is likely to occur without using exception handling. In other situations, using exception handling to catch an error condition is appropriate.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(VS.71).aspx)

That's what I found and it makes sense to me.. Check manually for the obvious things, let try-catch do the rest..

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert has a good blog on this, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions).

There is no point (except for "vexing" (see blog)) catching an exception unless you can do something useful; and in most cases you simply can't - so let it bubble (your UI should obviously cleanse and display something).

You might, however, have a "try/finally" to deal with resource management. Or even cleaner, a "using" block to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the absolute answer is completely conditional (how control do you have over the environment, what is the expected balance between performance and consistency and many others I'm sure), but generally speaking I always do, choosing the safety over the potentially slower performance.

Answer (score 0):

it always depend on what you want to achieve. A server not responding might be serious enough to stop all what the routine what doing, and the exception should be thrown to the caller.

In other cases, you don't care whether you failed to update the db or not. Then consuming the exception is OK.

Obviously, you don't want to show the stack trace to your end user, though, so you'll need to catch it somewhere.